# How to specify an ordered list in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a list of numbers that need to be ordered. Currently they are in the XML as such:

```
<value_1>0.2</value_1>
<value_2>0.4</value_2>
<value_3>0.6</value_3>
...
<value_N>1.8</value_N>
```

Is there a better way to do this such that it can be well defined in XSD and that the data is returned from a parser in the specified order?

**EDIT** Snippet of XSD:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value_1" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="value_2" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="value_3" type="xs:decimal"/>
        ...
        <xs:element name="value_N" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to have the schema enforce the order, or do you want to transform the XML so that it ends up ordered?  Also can you show us the snippet of XSD you have so far.

Comment: I want to enforce the order specified in the XML. It seems most parsers do this anyway, but I'd like to require it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elements in XML are inherently ordered per their order in the document.  This order is significant (unlike that of attributes) and will be preserved by parsers.

XML documents must have a single root element, so let's wrap your example elements in a single containing element:

```
<values>
  <value_1>0.2</value_1>
  <value_2>0.4</value_2>
  <value_3>0.6</value_3>
  <!-- ... -->
  <value_N>1.8</value_N>
</values>
```

An XSD can be written for this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="values">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value_1" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="value_2" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="value_3" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <!-- ... -->
        <xs:element name="value_N" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But an improvement is immediately obvious: Eliminate the indexing number from the component name:

```
<values>
  <value>0.2</value>
  <value>0.4</value>
  <value>0.6</value>
  <!-- ... -->
  <value>1.8</value>
</values>
```

The XSD for this improved XML is similarly streamlined (and also can actually handle an indefinite number of `value` elements as well):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="values">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:decimal" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now one might ask whether the XSD can enforce a ***sorted*** order on the elements such that

```
<values>
  <value>0.2</value>
  <value>0.4</value>
  <value>0.6</value>
</values>
```

would be valid, but

```
<values>
  <value>0.6</value>
  <value>0.2</value>
  <value>0.4</value>
</values>
```

would be invalid.

This is not possible to do in XSD 1.0, however XSD 1.1 can express such a constraint via assertions.

### Asserting sorted ordering in XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="values">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:decimal" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="every $v in value 
                       satisfies not(number($v) lt 
                                     number($v/preceding-sibling::value[1]))"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Credit**: The idea for the assertion test is based on [one from Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17360240/290085).