# Validate that one element's value is greater than another's

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have an XML document with this schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="numbers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="number1" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="number2" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="number3" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="number4" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="number5" type="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

For example,

```
<numbers>
   <number1>10</number1>
   <number2>20</number2>
   <number3>30</number3>
   <number4>40</number4>
   <number5>50</number5>
</numbers>
```

I would like to amend this schema so that each of the numbers must be greater than the
last. That is, number2 > number1, number3 > number2, number4 > number3, and
number5 > number4. I don't think it's possible with plain XSD, but is it
possible with XPATH inside of XSD?

Comment: This is possible in XSD 1.1 but not if you are using XSD 1.0. See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383683/how-to-specify-an-ordered-list-in-xsd)

Comment: Correct, as @sergioFC mentioned, by "plain XSD". you're probably thinking as XSD 1.0 (which cannot enforce a content-sorted ordering), while "XPATH inside of XSD" (via `xs:assert`) would require XSD 1.1.  Let us know in a comment and/or via `xsd-1.0` or `xsd-1.1` tags if you can use XSD 1.1 .  Thanks.